# Using Bootstrap Popovers in React without JSX

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to re-create this example without JSX:

http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers-overlay-trigger

In particular, this line is causing me a headache:

```
 <OverlayTrigger trigger='click' placement='left' overlay={<Popover title='Popover left'><strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.</Popover>}>
      <Button bsStyle='default'>Holy guacamole!</Button>
 </OverlayTrigger>
```

and my (more verbose) version:

```
React.createElement("div", {id:"some_id"},
    React.createElement(ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger, {container:"#some_id" , trigger:'click', placement:'left', overlay:
        React.createElement(ReactBootstrap.Popover, {'title':'Popover left'},
            React.createElement("strong", {}, "Check this info.")
        )
    })
)
```

The keyword "overlay" has me confused, as I'm not clear on how to rewrite it. I'm also unclear as to how to properly attach the mountNode to the parent div element, "#some_id". document.getElementbyId() doesn't work.

This is the error message I get when running the above:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo, it should be `document.getElementById()' , you have the "B" as "b" in the method name.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have any of these doubts, I suggest you to use an online transpiler to see how it looks once it is compiled.

Check it out [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3COverlayTrigger%20trigger%3D'click'%20placement%3D'left'%20overlay%3D%7B%3CPopover%20title%3D'Popover%20left'%3E%3Cstrong%3EHoly%20guacamole!%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20Check%20this%20info.%3C%2FPopover%3E%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CButton%20bsStyle%3D'default'%3EHoly%20guacamole!%3C%2FButton%3E%0A%20%3C%2FOverlayTrigger%3E).

PS: On a side note, if you don't like JSX because it mix JS and HTML I suggest you to use [ReactTemplates](http://wix.github.io/react-templates/).